# MySQL; Entity Framework; Too slow insert

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013

I'm sorry, it can be a perky question, but I don't know how to solve this. I have database on MySQL and I work with it using Entity FrameWork. Model looks like this : http://img42.com/yr36w+ (Stackoverflow doesn't want to load images, so i'll give you the link).

I have controller, that adds user with content and some details in my database, going through whole tables.
It creates:

1. user
2. details about him(name, address etc)
3. his content (0..10 links on images on my pc)
4. One his post
5. Adds links from this post to some of his content
6. Adds links from post to 0..10 users (users, that liked this post)

I want to go at least 10.000 times through this iteraion (creating 10k full accompanied users). I made some improvements from first version, they reduced perfoming time a lot, but anyway it takes too long. Now after 5k it needs like 3 seconds to go through iteration.

I don't know how to improve further. All methods work equally, but i'll give you whole controller for better understanding. Can you please say where my code has problem points? Please, any help is very useful for me, cause I really don't know in which direction to move.

```
string images = @"C:\Users\Kirill\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\MySQLMVC2\MySQLMVC2\Images";
    private static courseworkEntities db = new courseworkEntities();
    static Random randomizer = new Random();
    int postCategoryLength = db.postcategory.Count();
    int usersLength = db.user.Count();
    int countryLength = db.country.Count();


   private void createUser()
    {
        user newUser = db.user.Create();
        newUser.login = getRandomString(10);
        newUser.password = getRandomString(10);
        newUser.email = string.Concat(getRandomString(6), "@gmail.com".ToString());
        db.user.Add(newUser);
        db.SaveChanges();
        usersLength += 1;
        int iduser = newUser.iduser;
        createUserDetails(iduser);
        int howMuch = randomizer.Next(11);
        for(int i=0;i<howMuch;i++)
        createContent(iduser);
        createPost(iduser, howMuch);
    }

    private userdetails createUserDetails(int iduser)
    {
        userdetails newUserDetails = db.userdetails.Create();
        newUserDetails.Surname = getRandomString(10);
        newUserDetails.Name = getRandomString(10);
        newUserDetails.Phone = getRandomString(9);
        newUserDetails.iduserDetails = iduser;
        db.userdetails.Add(newUserDetails);
        db.SaveChanges();
        createAddress(newUserDetails.iduserDetails);
        return newUserDetails;
    }

    private post createPost(int iduser, int amountOfContent)
    {
        post newPost = db.post.Create();
        newPost.ownerId = iduser;
        int idPostCategory = randomizer.Next(1, postCategoryLength);
        newPost.postCategory = idPostCategory;
        newPost.Name = getRandomString(10);
        newPost.Description = getRandomString(10);
        newPost.CreateDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        db.post.Add(newPost);
        db.SaveChanges();
        int idpost = newPost.idpost;
        amountOfContent = randomizer.Next(0, amountOfContent+1);
        for (int i = 0; i < amountOfContent; i++)
        {
            createPostContent(newPost);
        }
        amountOfContent = randomizer.Next(0, Math.Min(usersLength, 10));
        for (int i = 0; i < amountOfContent; i++)
        {
            createUserLiked(idpost);
        }
        return newPost;
    }

    private postcontent createPostContent(post post)
    {
        postcontent newPostContent = db.postcontent.Create();
        newPostContent.postID = post.idpost;
        content content = post.user.content.ElementAt(randomizer.Next(0, post.user.content.Count()));
        newPostContent.contentId = content.idcontent;
        db.postcontent.Add(newPostContent);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return newPostContent;
    }

    private usersliked createUserLiked(int idpost)
    {
        usersliked newUsersLiked = db.usersliked.Create();
        newUsersLiked.postId = idpost;
        //int length = db.user.Count();
        //user user = post.user;
        int id = randomizer.Next(29, usersLength);
        //user user = db.user.Find(id);
        newUsersLiked.userId = id;
        db.usersliked.Add(newUsersLiked);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return newUsersLiked;
    }

    private address createAddress(int iduserDetails)
    {
        address newAddress = db.address.Create();
        newAddress.addressLine = getRandomString(20);
        newAddress.city = getRandomString(10);
        newAddress.postalCode = getRandomInt(6);
        newAddress.idaddress = iduserDetails;
        int idCountry = randomizer.Next(1, countryLength);
        newAddress.countryId = idCountry;
        db.address.Add(newAddress);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return newAddress;
    }

    private content createContent(int iduser)
    {
        content newContent = db.content.Create();
        newContent.ownerId = iduser;
        newContent.path = System.IO.Path.Combine(images, String.Concat(randomizer.Next(1, 500001).ToString(), ".jpg"));
        db.content.Add(newContent);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return newContent;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(int model)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < model;i++)
            createUser();
        try
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Comment: So as you add more rows it is getting slower and slower to insert? If yes then: what indexes do you have on the tables?

Comment: @Richard MySQL Workbench adds indexes on primary and foreign key values, if adding them through GUI, as I understood. But now I see, that their type is not defined : http://img42.com/6YFuh+ There is B-tree option, if I click on that button. Do you think, that problem may be here?

Comment: EF is probably also tracking state of every object you add. Some research will get you lots of ideas on how to improve bulk insert performance with EF (by disabling change tracking, limiting when you call `SaveChanges` etc) but the gist is it's not really built for it.

Comment: @CharlesMager What do you mean by gist? Gist index?

Comment: Not a technical term, just English - the essence, the general theme, the short version is EF isn't built for it.